# Auditing Entries in a server

Tags: windows-server-2016, properties

Whenever I right click on a folder, and go to the `security` tab then advanced, there is a tab for auditing.

[image]

My question is, whichever user or group we enter here, does it mean that only whatever these people do get's audited? or only these people can see the audits?

Also, when I press add, I get an almost grayed out window that has only `Select a principal` button. What is the principal and how does the auditing in general operates?

[image]